# Calling Task.wait may not wait if the task has not yet started?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

I was reading Jeffrey Richter's clr via c# book and felt uncomfortable reading that task wait may not always wait and I quote

> "When  a thread calls the Wait  method, the system checks if the Task 
>   that the thread is waiting for has started executing. If it has, then
>   the thread calling Wait  will block until the Task  has completed
>   running. But if the Task  has not started executing yet, then the
>   system may  (depending on the TaskScheduler ) execute the Task  by
>   using the thread that called Wait . If this happens, then the thread
>   calling Wait  does not block; it executes the Task  and returns
>   immediately."

Can some one please share more insight and in which case can such a scenario may happen?

Comment: [Task.Wait and “Inlining”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/15/9907713.aspx)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is unfortunately phrased. It's not that the `Wait` call returns before the task has finished executing; it's that the thread calling `Wait` may end up executing the task itself, rather than just blocking idly.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Make sure DemonstrateIssue is already called in a ThreadPool
        // thread...
        Task task = Task.Run((Action) DemonstrateIssue);
        task.Wait();
    }

    static void DemonstrateIssue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DemonstrateIssue thread: {0}",
                          Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Action action = () => Console.WriteLine("Inner task thread: {0}",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Task task = new Task(action);
        // Calling Start will just schedule it... we may be able to Wait
        // before it actually executed
        task.Start();
        task.Wait();
    }
}
```

Output every time I've run it:

```
DemonstrateIssue thread: 3
Inner task thread: 3
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the thread pool doesn't spin up threads *immediately* on demand - it waits for a while to see if an existing thread will become available before starting another one. If you add `Thread.Sleep(5000);` before the call to `task.Wait()`, you'll see the two tasks end up on different threads.

Comment: `returns immediately` is the offending section imo. That is entirely the wrong language to be using.

Comment: @Gusdor: Yes, absolutely. If you take into account the "executes the task" it's not *quite* as bad, but it's still very easy to misunderstand.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that was a big relief :).