# CLR via C# 4th Ed. - Confused about waiting for Task deadlock

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, clr, deadlock

Jeffrey Richter pointed out in his book 'CLR via C#' the example of a possible deadlock I don't understand (page 702, bordered paragraph).

The example is a thread that runs Task and call Wait() for this Task. If the Task is not started it should possible that the Wait() call is not blocking, instead it's running the not started Task. If a lock is entered before the Wait() call and the Task also try to enter this lock can result in a deadlock.

But the locks are entered in the same thread, should this end up in a deadlock scenario?

The following code produce the expected output.

```
class Program
{
    static object lockObj = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Program starts running on thread {0}",
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            var taskToRun = new Task(() =>
            {
                lock (lockObj)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} from Thread {1}", 
                            i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                }
            });

            taskToRun.Start();
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                taskToRun.Wait();
            }

        }).Wait() ;
    }
}

/* Console output
Program starts running on thread 3
0 from Thread 3
1 from Thread 3
2 from Thread 3
3 from Thread 3
4 from Thread 3
5 from Thread 3
6 from Thread 3
7 from Thread 3
8 from Thread 3
9 from Thread 3
*/
```

No deadlock occured.

J. Richter wrote in his book "CLR via C#" 4th Edition on page 702:

> When a thread calls the Wait method, the system checks if the Task that the thread is waiting for has started executing. If it has, then the thread calling Wait will block until the Task has completed running. But if the Task has not started executing yet, then the system may (depending on the TaskScheduler) execute the Trask by using the thread that called Wait. If this happens, then the thread calling Wait does not block; it executes the Task and returns immediatlely. This is good in that no thread has blocked, thereby reducing resource usage (by not creating a thread to replace the blocked thread) while improving performance (no time is spet to create a thread an there is no contexte switcing). But it can also be bad if, for example, thre thread has taken a thread synchronization lock before calling Wait and thren the Task tries to take the same lock, resulting in a deadlocked thread!

If I'm understand the paragraph correctly, the code above has to end in a deadlock!?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling Task.wait may not wait if the task has not yet started?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350177/calling-task-wait-may-not-wait-if-the-task-has-not-yet-started)

Comment: @Noseratio: This is not the same! The point is that the quoted paragraph describe a deadlock that should no occur when one thread reentrant a lock. Is a deadlock in the described quoted scenario possible?

Comment: Hmm, you do not seem interested in about how `Task` works but about how to get a single thread to deadlock itself by trying to “lock” a resource multiple times. Maybe that part of your question could be split off to a new question that doesn’t reference `Task`/TPL at all? ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're taking my usage of the word "lock" too literally. The C# "lock" statement (which my book discourages the use of), internally leverages Monitor.Enter/Exit. The Monitor lock is a lock that supports thread ownership & recursion. Therefore, a single thread can acquire this kind of lock multiple times successfully. But, if you use a different kind of lock, like a Semaphore(Slim), an AutoResetEvent(Slim) or a ReaderWriterLockSlim (without recursion), then when a single thread tries to acquire any of these locks multiple times, deadlock occurs.

Comment: This does make sense. Thanks for clarifying, Jeffrey.

Comment: That's the answer I'm waiting for. Now I understand what yout write :-). Thanks a lot for your post.

Comment: I was about to search for the exact same question heh. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

In this example, you're dealing with *task inlining*, a not-so-rare behavior of the TPL's default task scheduler. It results in the task being executed on the same thread which is already waiting for it with `Task.Wait()`, rather than on a random pool thread. In which case, there is no deadlock.

Change your code like below and you'll have a dealock:

```
taskToRun.Start();
lock (lockObj)
{
    //taskToRun.Wait();

    ((IAsyncResult)taskToRun).AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
}
```

The task inlining is nondeterministic, it may or may not happen. You should make no assumptions. Check [Task.Wait and “Inlining”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/15/9907713.aspx) by Stephen Toub for more details.

**Updated**, the lock *does not* affect the task inlining here. Your code still runs *without* deadlock if you move `taskToRun.Start()` inside the lock:

```
lock (lockObj)
{
    taskToRun.Start();
    taskToRun.Wait();
}
```

What *does* cause the inlining here is the circumstance that the main thread is calling `taskToRun.Wait()` right after `taskToRun.Start()`. Here's what happens behind the scene:

1. `taskToRun.Start()` queues the task for execution by the task scheduler, but it hasn't been allocated a pool thread yet.
2. On the same thread, the TPL code inside `taskToRun.Wait()` checks if the task has already been allocated a pool thread (it hasn't) and executes it inline on the main thread. In which case, it's OK to acquired the same lock twice without a deadlock.
3. There is also a TPL Task Scheduler thread. If this thread gets a chance to execute before `taskToRun.Wait()` is called on the main thread, inlining doesn't happen and you get a deadlock. Adding `Thread.Sleep(100)` before `Task.Wait()` would be modelling this scenario. Inlining also doesn't happen if you don't use `Task.Wait()` and rather use something like `AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()` above.

As to the quote you've added to your question, it depends on how you read it. One thing is for sure: the *same* lock from the main thread *can* be entered inside the task, when the task gets inlined, without a deadlock. You just cannot make any assumptions that it *will* get inlined.

Comment: That is absolute correct. I'm not sure if Richter is correct with his paragraph of task inlining. IMHO the deadlock cannot occur while the thread is always the same and that's what all guys are writing here.

Comment: @embee, the point is, it may not necessarily be the *same* thread, so Richter's code sample is technically correct. You really should not rely upon this inlining behavior.

Comment: The code sample is no from the book, I write it to illustrate the code that Richter described. I'm only confused that Richter writes, that this code should end up in Deadlock. I don't know if it's leagal to quote the paragraph here. If it's legal I can quote the original paragraph....

Answer (score 1):

In your example, no deadlock occurs because the thread scheduling the task and the thread executing the task happen to be the same.  If you were to modify the code such that your task ran on a different thread, you would see the deadlock occur, because two threads would then be contending for a lock on the same object.

Your example, modified to create a deadlock:

```
class Program {
    static object lockObj = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Program starts running on thread {0}",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        var taskToRun = new Task(() => {
            lock (lockObj) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} from Thread {1}",
                        i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            }
        });

        lock (lockObj) {
            taskToRun.Start();
            taskToRun.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is absolute correct, but in his book Jeffrey describe a scenario like my code sample. Do you have the book?

Comment: @embee cokeman19 is kind of right. Richter's code *might* cause a deadlock, but only if the two tasks are run on different threads. Whether they do run on different threads or not, is a matter of chance. You don't need to "radically" modify your code to prove this, like cokeman19 did. Just introduce a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` before both locks. Again, Richter's example is theoretically possible, but improbable in practice.

Comment: I don't have a problem with this in real code. I read the threading part of the fourth edition this afternoon and I stuck reading this part. Richter describe that a Task that is not started can be executed in the same thread where the Wait() call occur. The output shows this behavior but a deadlock is not present.

Comment: I found a copy of the book to which you're referring and, Richter does seem to be suggesting that locking on the same object multiple times within the same thread could potentially cause a deadlock.  However, lock is reentrant by design, so I am at a loss as to how that would be possible, unless as dcastro suggested, he is speaking strictly theoretically.

Answer (score 1):

This example code has **two** standard threading problems.  To understand it, you first have to understand thread races.  When you start a thread, you can *never* assume it will start running right away.  Nor can you assume that the code inside the thread arrives at a particular statement at a particular moment in time.

What matters a great deal here is whether or not the task arrives at the *lock* statement before the main thread does.  In other words, whether it races ahead of the code in the main thread.  Do model this as a horse race, the thread that acquired the lock is the horse that wins.

If it is the task that wins, pretty common on modern machines with multiple processor cores or a simple program that doesn't have any other threads active (and probably when you test the code) then nothing goes wrong.  It acquires the lock and prevents the main thread from doing the same when it, later, arrives at the lock statement.  So you'll see the console output, the task finishes, the main thread now acquires the lock and the Wait() call quickly completes.

But if the thread pool is already busy with other threads, or the machine is busy executing threads in other programs, or you are unlucky and you get an email just as the task starts running, then the code in the task doesn't start running right away and it is the main thread that acquired the lock first.  The task can now no longer enter the lock statement so it cannot complete.  And the main thread can not complete, Wait() will never return.  A deadly embrace called deadlock.

Deadlock is relatively easy to debug, you've got all the time in the world to attach a debugger and look at the active threads to see why they are blocked.  Threading race bugs are incredibly difficult to debug, they happen too infrequently and it can be very difficult to reason through the ordering problem that causes them.  A common approach to diagnose thread races is to add tracing to the program so you can see the order.  Which changes the timing and can make the bug disappear.  Lots of programs were shipped with the tracing left on because they couldn't diagnose the problem :)

Comment: You're correct, but Richter describe a scenario where only 'one' Thread process the main thread and the task. The task is not start excuting (on possbile another thread) when Wait() is called. Wait() and the TaskScheduler decide to run the Task with the current thread. In this situation you cannot get a deadlock !?

Comment: The task is eligible to start running when you call the Start() method.  Whether it does *right away* is something you cannot assume.  Nor can you assume that TaskScheduler will force it to run, that's an optimization that you cannot count on.  It certainly doesn't on my machine.  These are the kind of assumptions that cause threading bugs and is what Richter is warning you about.

Comment: Richter:
"But if the Task has not started executing yet, then the system may (depending on the TaskScheduler) execute the Trask by using the thread that called Wait."

This is what the program does. The tasked is executed on the ***same*** thread as the main thread. So, this would never end in a deadlock.

Comment: It is not what the program does on my machine, it deadlocks repeatedly.  Your "but if" is pointless, you must worry about the "but if not" cases.

Comment: This is not the race between the main thread and the task's thread. Rather, this is the race the between the main thread and the TPL Task Scheduler thread, which affects the task in-lining. This is well illustrated by moving `taskToRun.Start()` inside the `lock`: still no deadlock.

Comment: That's yet another assumption that will byte badly. The task can be pre-empted by the operating system's thread scheduler after it started running.  Reasoning about exactly *where* the race will occur is not meaningful, only thing that matters is that there *can* be a race.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jeffrey-richter for pointing it out, @embee there are scenario when we use locks other than Monitor than a single thread tries to acquire any of these locks multiple times, deadlock occurs. Check out the example below

The following code produce the expected deadlock. It need not be nested task the deadlock can occur without nesting also

```
class Program
{
    static AutoResetEvent signalEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Program starts running on thread {0}",
                 Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            var taskToRun = new Task(() =>
            {
                signalEvent.WaitOne();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} from Thread {1}", 
                        i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            });

            taskToRun.Start();
            signalEvent.Set();
            taskToRun.Wait();

        }).Wait() ;
    }
}
```