# How can BlockingCollection(T).GetConsumingEnumerable() throw OperationCanceledException?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm using a BlockingCollection to implement a task scheduler, basically:

```
public class DedicatedThreadScheduler : TaskScheduler, IDisposable
{
    readonly BlockingCollection<Task> m_taskQueue = new BlockingCollection<Task>();

    readonly Thread m_thread;


    public DedicatedThreadScheduler()
    {
        m_thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            foreach (var task in m_taskQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                TryExecuteTask(task);
            }
            m_taskQueue.Dispose();
        });
        m_thread.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        m_taskQueue.CompleteAdding();
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        return Thread.CurrentThread == m_thread && TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    (...)
}
```

I've only seen this once and couldn't reproduce this, but at some point on the foreach (in [TryTakeWithNoTimeValidation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs#3fc8b6e4e28ee36c)) I got an OperationCanceledException. I don't understand as I'm using the overload that doesn't take a CancellationToken, and [the documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) that it may only throw an ObjectDisposedException. What would the exception mean? That the blocking collection was finalized? That a task in the queue was cancelled?

Update: the call stack looks like this:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.WaitUntilCountOrTimeout(int millisecondsTimeout, uint startTime, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) + 0x36 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) + 0x178 bytes   
System.dll!System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>.TryTakeWithNoTimeValidation(out System.Threading.Tasks.Task item, int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource combinedTokenSource) Line 710 + 0x25 bytes   C#
System.dll!System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>.GetConsumingEnumerable(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 1677 + 0x18 bytes    C#
```

Comment: Have you examined the stack trace? The exception is probably occurring in a method that `BlockingCollection` calls.

Comment: Yes, as I added in the description, it occurs in TryTakeWIthNoTimeValidation. As far as I can tell by looking at the source, it should only throw OperationCanceledException if it was passed a CancellationToken, but I use the overload that doesn't...

Comment: Updated the question with the call stack.

Comment: There is no interlock between the Dispose() method and the foreach loop.  Usually works fine, not when for some reason Dispose() is called too soon.

Comment: @HansPassant That should be ok because the blocking collection's Dispose() is necessarily called after the foreach, on the same thread. The Dispose() method of the class only calls CompleteAdding() which prevents new tasks from being queued.

Comment: Another "how can it not fail" race condition in this code is you calling your outer Dispose() method after the thread disposed the queue.  That's a guaranteed OBE.  Very hard to see how you prevent that, I'll readily assume we can't see enough of the code.

Comment: I'm noticing OperationCanceledException getting thrown in my application using GetConsumingEnumerable() on a blocking collection too. No idea how or why.

Comment: I think your debugger is just set to break when OperationCanceledException is thrown. TryExecuteTaskInline() will actaully catch the OperationCanceledException and will return false if no cancellation token is set or if cancellation is not requested.

Comment: @Asik Hans is taking about the sequence of events `outer.Dispose()`, wait for `m_thread` to complete, 2nd call to `outer.Dispose()`. Dispose needs to be able to be called multiple times without throwing a error, your Dispose throws a `ObjectDisposedException`, please [read the documentation for Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ah, that's correct. As this was not a public-facing library IIRC I had voluntarily left it that way to catch weird dispose behaviors in calling code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an old question, but I'll add the full answer for anyone that finds it in the future. The answer provided by Eugene is partly correct; at the time you must have been debugging with Visual Studio configured to break on handled framework exceptions.

However, the actual reason you were breaking on an `OperationCanceledException` is that the code for `BlockingCollection<T>.CompleteAdding()` looks like this:

```
    public void CompleteAdding()
    {
        int num;
        this.CheckDisposed();
        if (this.IsAddingCompleted)
        {
            return;
        }
        SpinWait wait = new SpinWait();
    Label_0017:
        num = this.m_currentAdders;
        if ((num & -2147483648) != 0)
        {
            wait.Reset();
            while (this.m_currentAdders != -2147483648)
            {
                wait.SpinOnce();
            }
        }
        else if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.m_currentAdders, num | -2147483648, num) == num)
        {
            wait.Reset();
            while (this.m_currentAdders != -2147483648)
            {
                wait.SpinOnce();
            }
            if (this.Count == 0)
            {
                this.CancelWaitingConsumers();
            }
            this.CancelWaitingProducers();
        }
        else
        {
            wait.SpinOnce();
            goto Label_0017;
        }
    }
```

Notice these particular lines:

```
if (this.Count == 0)
{
    this.CancelWaitingConsumers();
}
```

which call this method:

```
private void CancelWaitingConsumers()
{
    this.m_ConsumersCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

So even though you weren't explicitly using a `CancellationToken` in your code, the underlying framework code throws an `OperationCanceledException` if the `BlockingCollection` is empty when `CompleteAdding()` is called. It does this to signal the `GetConsumingEnumerable()` method to exit. The exception is handled by the framework code and you wouldn't have noticed it if you hadn't had your debugger configured to intercept it.

The reason you couldn't replicate it is because you placed your call to `CompleteAdding()` in your `Dispose()` method. Therefore, it was getting called at the whim of the GC.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! I guess the obvious next question is do I need to handle this exception and if so how? This is very likely to happen when there are many producers but far fewer consumers.

Comment: No, you don't need to handle it. It's simply used as an internal signalling mechanism. You'll only be aware of it if your debugger is configured to intercept it.

Answer (score 2):

I can only speculate, but I think you may be experiencing the task inlining scenario described by Stephen Toub in his ["Task.Wait and “Inlining”"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/15/9907713.aspx) blog post and by Jon Skeet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21350200/1768303).

What does your implementation of `TaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline` look like? To prevent unexpected task inlining, always return `false`:

```
override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Added implementation of TryExecuteTaskInline to the question. I'll try to see if this happens when that method is called, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2):

That exception occasionally happens inside MoveNext() method of GetConsumingEnumerable enumerator, but it's a handled exception, so normally you shouldn't see it.

Perhaps you have debugger configured to break on handled exceptions (in Visual Studio, these options are in Debug/Exceptions menu), in this case the debugger may break even on exceptions happening inside .NET framework functions.

Comment: This isn't the whole story. I'll put the real reason in a separate answer.